# Multiple AJAX calls using the same AJAX functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am looking to fire off several jQuery AJAX requests in quick succession, so the response will not come before the next request. However, I do want to handle each one of these responses with the success function.

With the following code, the first two responses will be ignored and only the last one will respond.

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    var num = 3;
    for(var i=0;i<num;i++)
        ajaxCall(i);
}


function ajaxCall(data){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/html/',
        success: function(msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

However I am trying to make it so that all three alerts would show up. It seems that each time the `ajaxCall` function is called it uses the same 'object' as it did the previous time instead of instantiating a new one, which is what I want to do.

Comment: Try adding `async: false` to the Ajax call, does this change the behavior?

Comment: I get 3 alerts:  http://jsfiddle.net/NhrBt/  You are missing a closing `);` on your `click` though.

Comment: Are you getting sucess for all 3 ? check in the network log for developer tool, how many requests are being sent and what response are you getting.

Comment: I am getting network responses, but the success function doesn't happen, it just gets ignored by the function.

Comment: Why are you not using the 'data' that you are passing to ajaxCall?

Comment: @MattBaumgartner, you should fix your snippet. And, try it before posting it. (Notice your snippet doesn't work because of syntax errors and nothing else)

Comment: checked the fiddle by James, it sends only one HTTP request but sucess is called for each!

Comment: Ok, I messed up the syntax (sorry). I too got it to work on fiddle which I can't understand how this doesn't work for me. If the response time were to be much longer, would that bring in issues that I am seeing?

Comment: @MattBaumgartner, it's irrelevant (while it doesn't timeout.) Make a [real example](http://sscce.org/) and come back

Answer (score -1):

Try this (using [Deferred Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/))

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    var num = 3;
    for(var i=0;i<num;i++) {
        ajaxCall(i).done(function(data) 
           { 
             alert(data) 
           }
        );
     }
});


function ajaxCall(data){
    return $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/html/'
    });
}
```

Comment: This is overdoing it. If you still want to use it, there you go

Comment: Copying the mistake of the question owner: Close the click function.

Comment: And why is it overdoing? A little birdie told me this : Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks will be deprecated in jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

Comment: @user1860370, *that little birdie* certainly didn't mention *properties*